# React Native - Acceptable Amount of Memory Usage

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

I have a basic react native app that uses [React Native Maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) to display the location markers (whose latitude & longitude is pulled from my API).

However, this app is using well over 200MB of memory on the iPhone 7 simulator. Is this normal? I've developed apps using `Swift` before and the memory usage was rarely ever over 100MB.

If I make a sample app, simply using this file they've provided in their examples, it's still using over 200MB of memory: [Draggable Markers](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DraggableMarkers.js)

Comment: Can you try profiling it with Xcode instruments?  Does the memory usage stay constant or increase over time as you interact with it?  That's a high level of memory usage, but if it doesn't keep growing forever, you're probably OK ...